# Permalink structure not working with Custom Taxonomy (URL like ./taxonomy/category/postname)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I want to publish and organize issues with WordPress. The magazine is structured into issues (for example Magazine n°23), categories (always the same categories regardless the issue) and finally posts.

I would like to have the following URL structure `example.com/issue-X/Y/Z` with X for the issue number, Y for the category and Z for the post name.

---

### My code

The easiest way will be to use WordPress built-in `post` Post Type and the `category` taxonomy. I have created a custom taxonomy for the issues, named `magazine_issue` and linked to `post`:

```
function jt_magazine_issue_taxonomy()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Numéros', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'twentysixteen'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Numéro', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'twentysixteen'),
        'menu_name' => __('Numéros', 'twentysixteen'),
        'all_items' => __('Tous les numéros', 'twentysixteen'),
        'parent_item' => __('Numéro parent', 'twentysixteen'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Numéro parent :', 'twentysixteen'),
        'new_item_name' => __('Nom', 'twentysixteen'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Ajouter un nouveau numéro', 'twentysixteen'),
        'edit_item' => __('Modifier le numéro', 'twentysixteen'),
        'update_item' => __('Mettre à jour', 'twentysixteen'),
        'view_item' => __('Voir le numéro', 'twentysixteen'),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate items with commas', 'twentysixteen'),
        'add_or_remove_items' => __('Ajouter ou supprimer des numéros', 'twentysixteen'),
        'choose_from_most_used' => __('Les plus utilisées', 'twentysixteen'),
        'popular_items' => __('Numéros populaires', 'twentysixteen'),
        'search_items' => __('Rechercher dans les numéros', 'twentysixteen'),
        'not_found' => __('Aucun numéro trouvé', 'twentysixteen'),
        'no_terms' => __('Aucun numéros', 'twentysixteen'),
        'items_list' => __('Liste des numéros', 'twentysixteen'),
        'items_list_navigation' => __('Items list navigation', 'twentysixteen'),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => false,
        'rewrite' => false,
    );
    register_taxonomy('magazine_issue', array('post'), $args);
}

add_action('init', 'jt_magazine_issue_taxonomy', 0);
```

Notice that I have set the rewrite property to `false`.

In order to set up my custom URL structure I used the `rewrite_rules_array` filter:

```
function jt_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newRules  = array();

    $newRules['issue-(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[3]';
    $newRules['issue-(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[2]';
    $newRules['issue-(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?magazine_issue=$matches[1]';

    return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'jt_rewrite_rules');
```

Then I add this code to handle the `%magazine_issue%` when I create or update a post:

```
function jt_magazine_issue_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%magazine_issue%') === FALSE) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    // Get post
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if (!$post) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    // Get taxonomy terms
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'magazine_issue');
    if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0]))
        $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    else
        $taxonomy_slug = 'inconnu';

    return str_replace('%magazine_issue%', 'numero-'.$taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}

add_filter('post_link', 'jt_magazine_issue_permalink', 10, 3);
```

The permalink structure in WordPress backend is set to:

`/%magazine_issue%/%category%/%postname%/`

---

### What works

- `example.com/issue-X/` redirect to the taxonomy archive
- `example.com/issue-X/Y/` redirect to the built-in WordPress category
  archive

---

### What does not work

- `example.com/issue-X/Y/Z/` doesn't redirect to the post (single.php) => 404 error

Even a direct call to `index.php?pagename=Z` failed (404 error).

---

Any solutions?

Thanks and happy new years!

Guillaume

---

### Update (solution)

Thanks to Milo the "problem" is resolved (`postname` must be replaced with `name`, which the keywork for built-in post's name).

```
$newRules['issue-(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?name=$matches[3]';
```

Comment: `pagename` is the query var for the `page` post type, `name` is for `post`s.

Comment: Thank you SO much, it's working fine with `name`. This has been driving me nuts for too much hours! Too much work for today!